# How to give a script access to protected tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs for each manager and an archive tab. At the moment, I have a script in place that will automatically remove the row from a managers tab and put into the archive. For Data protection, no manager has access to the other managers tabs or the archive.

Now this is where the issue is to deny access to the other tabs they are protected but this stops the script from running as its sending to a protected tab.

How can I get around this without giving them access?

The tabs are hidden and protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making a web app worked with a trigger but the web app and trigger must be done by the document owner.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).